# Spring authentication not available in a user created thread

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-3

I am using spring based authentication by implementing UserDetailsService. Following is my spring config

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="authenticationService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
            <salt-source ref="authenticationService"/>
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

My authentication service looks like:

```
public class AuthenticationServiceImpl implements AuthenticationService, UserDetailsService, SaltSource {
    ....
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException { 
        ....
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, authorities);
    }
 }
```

Now the problem is when I create a new thread from one of my spring controllers. How do I authenticate my user in that thread ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loadUserByUsername), password));
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a better solution, to set it in configuration itself. Using following code:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass"
              value="org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="setStrategyName"/>
    <property name="arguments"><b:list><b:value>MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL</value></list></property>
</bean>
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: N.B. That only works if the threads are created by a parent that contains the SecurityContext.  If you use a thread pool (which would be best practice) that won't be the case.